# Help identify Mega Bloks set with red, blue and metallic gold elements

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

I found this set in my garage. It belongs to my son but we don't have the instructions and since we don't know the name or theme of the set we can't find it online. I don't even know if everything is supposed to be together!
Some parts broke sadly.

[image]